# Can the specific heat capacity in the Ising Model be negative?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, simulations, ising-model

Im working on a numerical method for the Ising model. I'm asked to calculate both the absolute magnetizetion and the specific heat capacity:
$$c = \frac{\beta^2}{N} \left( \langle H^2 \rangle - \langle H \rangle^2 \right)$$

$$m_{\text{abs}} = \frac{1}{N} \langle \lvert \sum_{x}  s_x \rvert \rangle$$

When plotting the resulting values against $\beta$  (inverse temperature of the system)  I get normal results in contrast to other studies, but I have negative Heat Capacity values for low temperatures, which I havent seen anywhere else. Is there any problem or my simulations are correct?[image][image]

Comment: There is definitely a problem with your simulation or calculations. $\langle H^2\rangle - \langle H \rangle^2$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Have you check finite size effects? Is it 2D model?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov This cannot be finite size effects. See the comment by Gec.

Comment: To elaborate on @Gec's point, the [covariance inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) requires that the expectation value of $H$ satisfies $E(H^2) \geq [E(H)]^2$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It's actually even more basic than that: a variance is always nonnegative since ${\rm Var}(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2 = E\bigl((X-E(X))^2\bigr) \geq 0$.